# How to publish message evenly to multiple queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm new in RabbitMQ. I tried to check if it's possible to send messages evenly to multiple queues. I did some research but unable to find any satisfy info/answers.

I want to achieve something similar as Kafka Topic's partition, but using RabbitMQ.

For example, let say:

2 Queues : Q1 and Q2.
5 message : M1, M2, M3, M4, M5

I want the message to distribute evenly to the queues through exchange:

Q1: M1, M3, M5
Q2: M2, M4

I understand that I can use the routing key to route to specific queue. However, my message is a general type which I can't group then by some key.

May I know if this is achievable in RabbitMQ?